# Access of static variables from one class to another

Tags: java, android

I'm having a hard time trying to understand static variables. Can anybody explain why when I call the variable 'startingDate' in FragmentJoy, it doesn't return the correct value? Assume all the rest of the code is working perfectly, not NULL values and databaseCategories is working fine. How can I save a value inside 'onDataChange()' method and use it in FragmentJoy?

I CANNOT remove:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {)
```

This is dashboard activity

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

static String startingDate;
DatabaseReference databaseCategories;
ArrayList<Category> currentJoyCategories;


User currentUser; //holds the information of the current user


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    . . . . . .

    databaseCategories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories");

    currentJoyCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    databaseCategories.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               //want to do
               startingDate = "some string";
         }

         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
} //end of Dashboard class
```

In Another class I want to do:

```
public class FragmentJoy extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_joy,container,false);

         //not storing the string "some string"
        System.out.println("testing " + Dashboard.startingDate);

        return view;

} //end of onCreateView method
} //end of class
```

Comment: Better way is to create interface for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `startingDate` as `public static String startingDate`

**use this**

```
public static String startingDate;
```

**instead of this**

```
static String startingDate;
```

Then you can use it in your `FragmentJoy` like this

```
Log.e("testing ",Dashboard.startingDate);
```

Comment: OK but are you sure it is generally a good idea to make a class level non constant variable public like this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nop

Comment: its returning NULL still

Comment: @Lazaro are your sure you are adding some value in string

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes thanks for responding, inside create(), I know I can do startingDate = "example" and it works. The problem is inside  onDataChange() method which is inside onCreate()

Comment: @NileshRathod I don't know if this matters but inside onDataChange() method, I have 2 nested for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) loops.

Comment: try to check in that ` dataSnapshot.getChildren())` that you getting any value in your string or not

Comment: @NileshRathod yes I'm printing all the for loops and its working fine. I even debug the code and before exiting the onDataChange() method, startingDate has the correct value that I want.

Comment: @Lazaro you forgot to add `return view;` in your `FragmentJoy`

Comment: It's near the bottom of the original code, I didn't want to paste 500 lines here.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I showing you how to use static method of one `class` to another class.

e.g. I have defined one static method in class `HomeFragment`,

public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

```
    Unbinder unbinder;
    int mode;

    public static HomeFragment getInstance(int mode) {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(KeyUtil.KEY_MODE, mode);
        homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return homeFragment;
    }
    ....................
}
```

And, I have used this `static` method in My `MainActivity` class,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...........................

        /**
         * Get the fragment while need to push.
         *
         * @return: fragment
         */
        private Fragment openFragment() {
            switch (navItemIndex) {
                case 0:
                    // Here I have called static method
                    return HomeFragment.getInstance(0);
                }
         }

        ........................
    }
```